# Changes to a container while BOOST_FOREACH is iterating through it?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-foreach

What would happen if a container that BOOST_FOREACH is iterating through is changed inside the BOOST_FOREACH scope?

Does BOOST_FOREACH "freeze" the initial state?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case behavior is undefined. Look at [Hoisting and Iterator Invalidation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/foreach/pitfalls.html) in official documentation of `BOOST_FOREACH`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it depends on the container.

The real question is, whether the (remaining) iterator range for traversal is invalidated or not.

This depends on the change. `std` algorithms are specified with their behaviour: they mention what iterators are invalidated when.

#### Update

It can also depend on the type of iterator,

- `vector::erase` invalidates all subsequent iterators
- `list::erase` does not